# Sending large data to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Is it possible to send large amount of data (grid content for example) in `$.ajax`, to controller?
Are there workarounds of "URI too long" thing?
I know it's probably not the best practice, instead I should probably send each row one by one, but still is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there workarounds of "URI too long" thing?

Use a POST HTTP verb instead of GET:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { value: someVariableThatCouldBeHuge },
    success: function(result) {
        // TODO: process the results
    }
});
```

or the equivalent:

```
$.post('/foo', { value: someVariableThatCouldBeHuge }, function(result) {
    // TODO: process the results
});
```