# Next.js 14 App Router - Pass data from client component to server component

Tags: next.js, next.js13, app-router, next.js14

I have a next.js project where I am using App Router which has page.tsx file. It has API to get data from the database.

Now I have a client side component which is used on this page which has interactivity. Client can fill in the form or move the animation which has listeners to change the request data.

I was pushing the request data to the router and on the page.tsx page, I was calling the API again based on the query parameter. But now the request data is huge as user change the animation so I cannot pass the data to the router.

I tried passing the data to local storage but I cannot access the local storage from the server component. I tried passing the data to cookies from the client but it says that data limit size has increased.

What is a way in next.js to pass the data from client component to server so server component can watch for it and call the API again?

Comment: maybe this could be useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774219/what-is-the-best-practice-for-passing-large-amounts-of-client-side-data-to-the-s

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store data for both of client and server component, you should use cookie instead of local storage.

It's available in server action.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies